# Kill a process that opened a file, after the file is closed by the user [WPF application]

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5

I am trying to efficiently open-close-reopen a power bi file (.pbix) from a WPF application button click. My method starts by creating a process that opens the pbix file then kills the process when the file is closed and then when the button is clicked again creates a new process to re-open the file.

Kindly find below the code I use to execute the steps above.

```cs
namespace TestApp
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int CheckFileIsOpen(string filenamepath)
        {
            try
            {
                using FileStream fs = new FileStream(filenamepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                WindowEffect = new BlurEffect();
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
                bool? Result = new CustomMessageBox($"File: {filenamepath.Split(@"\").Last()} in use!\nClose it and try again.", "File used by another process", MessageType.Error, MessageButtons.Ok).ShowDialog(); //this is a MessageBox object
                if (Result.Value)
                {
                    WindowEffect = null;
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    WindowEffect = null;
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        }

        private void OpenOnlineLocally(bool open_local)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            string copy_name = "File_Copy.pbix";
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; //the directory the .exe file runs.
            try
            {
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
                if (open_local == true)
                {
                    int IsPBIFileOpen = CheckFileIsOpen($@"{path}{copy_name}");
                    if (new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(IsPBIFileOpen))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    //Open the file using the system process
                    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo($"{path}{copy_name}")
                    {
                        UseShellExecute = true
                    };
                    p.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    OpenUrl("https://app.powerbi.com/...");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (p.HasExited) { p.Kill(); } //kill the process if the user closed the .pbix file
            }
        }

        public ICommand ExportPowerBICommand //binded to a button click command in xaml
        {
            get { return new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncExportPowerBI); }
        }
        public void FuncExportPowerBI(object parameter)
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
            try
            {
                OpenOnlineLocally(true);
            }
            finally
            {
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code generates this error in the `finally statement`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No process is associated with this object.'

Some notes after experimentation:

1. The process should be killed when the user closes the .pbix file (i.e. clicks the X icon on top right corner of the desktop app). If the process is not killed and the user *re-clicks* the button to *re-open* the file then I get an error that the file is already opened and used by another process.
2. I prefer to avoid a solution that uses `process.WaitForExit()`, for two reasons. First, the application freezes while the file is used by the user. Second, it takes a couple of seconds for the desktop to realize that the process has exited so it can `kill()` it (not time efficient).

Comment: You're trying to kill the already exited process. Fix: `if (!p.HasExited) { p.Kill(); }`

Comment: @aepot if I try the false scenario ```!p.HasExited``` the process never starts at all, because it is instantly killed. Please check the code I have uploaded to replicate the issue.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @aepot I use the 3.1 version on VS 2019

Comment: Any chance to migrate to .NET 5? There's easy solution in .NET 5. Or you need a solution for 3.1 only?

Comment: If I run ```dotnet-version``` on cmd I get back 5.0.101, So I basically have 5.0 but I think the wpf is built on .NET Core 3.1...that's what the folder says were the .exe file exists.

Comment: The progect is targeting .NET Core 3.1. Are you able to change the Target Framework to .NET 5? If yes, there's very simple solution. That's why I asking.

Comment: @aepot w8 because I need to check online how I can do that

Comment: Right click on the project in Solution Explorer => Properties => Application tab => change Target framework. Also 5.0.101 - not the very latest version, looks like you need to install an update for Visual Studio and SDK but it's not a critical thing.

Comment: @aepot ok Done! I was going for the project file

Comment: Careful with project file. .NET 5 .cproj settings are different from .NET Core 3.1 one. Just confirm that you able to run the app on .NET 5 and I'll post the answer.

Comment: @aepot yeah I can run the application

Comment: Change `.net` tag to `.net-5` in the post then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running .NET 5, there's an asynchronous method [Process.WaitForExitAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync?view=net-5.0). Async operation will not block the UI.

I've made the changes to two methods

```cs
private async Task OpenOnlineLocally(bool open_local)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    string copy_name = "File_Copy.pbix";
    string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; //the directory the .exe file runs.
    string path = Path.Combine(dir, copy_name);
    try
    {
        if (open_local == true)
        {
            int IsPBIFileOpen = CheckFileIsOpen(path);
            if (IsPBIFileOpen != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Open the file using the system process
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path)
            {
                UseShellExecute = true
            };
            p.Start();
            await p.WaitForExitAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            OpenUrl("https://app.powerbi.com/...");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!p.HasExited) { p.Kill(); } //kill the process if the user closed the .pbix file
    }
}

public async void FuncExportPowerBI(object parameter)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    try
    {
        await OpenOnlineLocally(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); // handle possible exception here
    }
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the asynchronous answer aepot. Just a minor edite, change ```!p.HasExited``` to ```p.HasExited``` because the process instantly exits when the user closes the file. So everything will work and the user may re-open the file as many times as he wants.

Comment: @NikSp you don't need to kill the already exited process (nothing to kill). It has no sense. Just remove that line then.

Comment: Yeah but ```!p.HasExited``` will generate an error that there is no associated process to kill.

Comment: @NikSp just remove that line. `WaitForExitAsync` make the process always exited for the further code lines.

Comment: Ok aepot. Besides that, the solution works as expectidely. Thank a lot for your contribution :)

Comment: @NikSp also consider to disable the button while Process is executing to prevent multiple executions at once (if necessary).

Comment: aepot just a quick question when ```WaitForExitAsync()``` exits it take a couple of seconds (~10'') to re-enable the button. Is this because my laptop is slow and takes time to windows to understand when the process is killed? Or is it something else that increasing the time?

Comment: @NikSp how do you disable it? `ICommand` CanExecute?

Comment: No. I have binded the property .Enable of the button in a MVVM model and I set it to false. For example, ButtonIsEnabled=false and true when the process is killed. Is CanExecute command faster?

Comment: @NikSp `IsEnabled` Property? If your implementation of DelegarCommand's CanExecute attached to `RequerySuggested` event, then you must call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` manually right after `await` is finished. But yes, `CanExecute` is more correct way to implement this. Btw, i have no idea what exactly cause the button state freezing.

Comment: 1.Yes ```IsEnabled```--
2. Yeah it freezes for a couple of seconds.--
3. I may try the ```CanExecute``` approach

Comment: @NikSp can you show the code that freeze the property e.g. link to pastebin site here in comment?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fItBETkumOeA3BCg7usDflqIUtxWOh5e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NikSp `if (!p.HasExited)` - remove that. Btw, i can't find any reasons for freeze. Maybe the process is really exiting slowly.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that maybe my laptop is running out of RAM, so it's a system problem not a code prob'

Comment: @NikSp one more issue `get { return new DelegateCommand..` meand you're creating new instance of the DelegateCommand each time when you or UI asking for it. Cache it in some local variable on firest call e.g. `private ICommand _exportPowerBICommand; public ICommand ExportPowerBICommand => _exportPowerBICommand ??= new DelegateCommand<object>(FuncExportPowerBI);`

Comment: Ok corrected it. Thank you for all the advices